# Hosting Java Server on LInux Virtual Machine

Tags: java, sockets, server, virtual

I am trying to host a Java server on Linux (Ubuntu 13) virtual machine on VirtualBox. I have to connect a client locally to the server via sockets. I am having trouble setting up the ip address and port for the client to find the server socket on the virtual machine.

Comment: You're having trouble? Me too. I am having trouble finding any useful information in the question that would allow us to help you. --- Recommend you read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

1. you should get the IP address on the VM
2. then ping the IP address from your CMD, if it's ok, then trying to run Java program, if not, you should focus on the VM configuration.

About your code, you can always run a Java socket server just on Windows and using a Java client to connect, after successfully test the code. You can launch the server code in VM.